# Am I using eq(...) incorrectly? Or what is wrong here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a block of HTML like

```
<tbody>
   <tr id="first-score-row">
      <td>Steve Ballmer</td>
      <td>1923</td>
      <td class="hide-under-480px">10/11/2015 9:21:39 PM</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
         <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg show-fewer-or-more-scores" id="show-more-scores">Click to See More</a></p>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="hidden">
      <td>Michael Jackson</td>
      <td>300</td>
      <td class="hide-under-480px">10/6/2015 2:37:30 PM</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="hidden">
      <td>Weird Al</td>
      <td>180</td>
      <td class="hide-under-480px">10/10/2015 1:20:38 AM</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="hidden">
      <td>Obama smokes cigs</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td class="hide-under-480px">10/5/2015 10:28:37 PM</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="hidden">
      <td>Donald Trump</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td class="hide-under-480px">10/5/2015 10:28:02 PM</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="hidden">
      <td colspan="3">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
               <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg show-fewer-or-more-scores" id="show-fewer-scores" target="_blank">See Fewer Scores</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
               <p><a href="/Scores" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" target="_blank">See <u>All</u> Scores</a></p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

and I'm trying to make an event that reveals or hides all the rows besides the first one (which will always be revealed) in animated fashion, 1/5th of a second between each one being revaled. My attempted event handler is

```
// click function for the "See More Scores" and "See Fewer Scores" buttons
$('.show-fewer-or-more-scores').click(function ( )
{
    var otherRows = $(this).closest('tbody').children('tr:not(#first-score-row)');
    for (var k = 0, n = otherRows.length; k < n; ++k)
    {
        setTimeout(function () {
                    otherRows.eq(k).toggleClass('hidden');
                   }, k * 200 );
    }

});
```

and for some reason it is not working. There are no errors printed to the console, but nothing happens, the class `hidden` is not toggled. What am I doing wrong here?

Live example [here](http://playclassicsnake.com/play)

Comment: why you use `setTimeOut`?

Comment: If I am not wrong then `toggleClass` is working only for the last row?

Comment: The problem is the value of `k` inside the timeout call

Comment: `$('.show-fewer-or-more-scores').click(function ( )
{
    var otherRows = $(this).closest('tbody').children('tr:not(#first-score-row)');
    for (var k = 1, n = otherRows.length; k < n; ++k)
    {
        otherRows.eq(k).toggleClass('hidden');
        
    }

});`

Comment: Its forming a closure..move your method outside the loop

Comment: Something like this: `setTimeout(toggleClass(k), k * 200 );

function toggleClass(k){

     return otherRows.eq(k).toggleClass('hidden');
                  
}`  Put the `toggleClass` outside the loop

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w73fh310/1/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To target ***All rows but first one*** use the `:gt(0)` selector:

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/vecumu/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

```
var $rowsNotFirst = $("table tbody tr:gt(0)");
var $scoresBtn = $(".show-fewer-or-more-scores");


$scoresBtn.click(function(){
  $rowsNotFirst.toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

To add the **timeout**:

**[jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/vecumu/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output)**

```
$scoresBtn.click(function(){
  $rowsNotFirst.filter(function(idx, el){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(el).toggleClass("hidden");
    }, 300*idx);                          // 300 * element index
  });
});
```

Comment: Will `el` not be undefined by the time the timeout executes here?

Comment: @DerFlatulator no, cause it's passed by the `.filter()` argument.

Comment: TIL, I think. I usually use function `.bind` in similar cases.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced your for loop with a jQuery each function.

```
otherRows.each(function(i){
           setTimeout(function () {
                otherRows.eq(i).toggleClass('hidden');
               }, i * 200 );
});
```

Dont forget the .hidden class, something like:

```
.hidden {display:none}
```

Other than that it works fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/partypete25/nvbraokh/20/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is here.

```
setTimeout(function () {
 otherRows.eq(k).toggleClass('hidden');
}, k * 200 );
```

The value of k will be equal to the value of n once the for loop is completed. So everytime when this line is called, the k value will be same, but no table row exists with that index value.

You have to get the table row element and then add the method toggleClass to it.